# Reset and create variables before FOR loop in a WHILE loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.5

I came across a MIT open source Python coding practice as

> Suppose you want to be able to afford the down payment in three years. How much should you save each month to achieve this? In this problem, you are going to write a program to answer that question. To simplify things, assume:
>        **1.** Your semi-annual raise is .07 (7%)
>        **2.** Your investments have an annual return of 0.04 (4%)
>        **3.** The down payment is 0.25 (25%) of the cost of the house.
>        **4.** The cost of the house that you are saving for is $1M.
>
> You are now going to try to find the best rate of savings to achieve a down payment on a $1M house in 36 months. Since hitting this exactly is a challenge, we simply want your savings to be within $100 of the required down payment. Write a program to calculate the best savings rate, as a function of your starting salary. You should use [bisection search] to help you do this efficiently. You should keep track of the number of steps it takes your bisections search to finish. Limit floats to two decimals of accuracy (i.e., we may want to save at 7.04% - or 0.0704 in decimal - but we are not going to worry about the delta between 7.041% and 7.039%). This means we can search for an integer between 0 and 10000 (using integer division), and then convert it to a decimal percentage (using float division) to use when we are calculating the current_savings after 36 months. Using this range gives us only a finite number of numbers that we are searching over, as opposed to the infinite number of decimals between 0 and 1. This range will help prevent infinite loops. The reason we use 0 to 10000 is to account for two additional decimal places in the range 0% to 100%. Your code should print out a decimal (e.g. 0.0704 for 7.04%).
>    Keep in mind that it may not be possible to save on a down payment in a year  and a half for some salaries. In this case your function should notify the user that it is not possible to save for the down payment in 36 months with a print statement.
>
> EXAMPLE OUTPUT
> Enter the starting salary: 150000
> Best savings rate: 0.4411
> Steps in bisection search: 12

The following is one of the solutions that I found.

```
# user input
annual_salary = float(input('Enter your annual salary: '))

# static variables and initializers
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
r = 0.04
portion_down_payment = 0.25
total_cost = 1000000
steps = 0
current_savings = 0
low = 0
high = 10000
guess_rate = (high + low)//2
# Use a while loop since we check UNTIL something happens.
while abs(current_savings - total_cost*portion_down_payment) >= 100:
    # Reset current_savings at the beginning of the loop
    current_savings = 0
    # Create a new variable for use within the for loop.
    for_annual_salary = annual_salary
    # convert guess_rate into a float
    rate = guess_rate/10000
    # Since we have a finite number of months, use a for loop to calculate
    # amount saved in that time.
    for month in range(36):
        # With indexing starting a zero, we need to calculate at the beginning
        # of the loop.
        if month % 6 == 0 and month > 0:
            for_annual_salary += for_annual_salary*semi_annual_raise
        # Set monthly_salary inside loop where annual_salary is modified
        monthly_salary = for_annual_salary/12
        # Calculate current savings
        current_savings += monthly_salary*rate+current_savings*r/12
    # The statement that makes this a bisection search
    if current_savings < total_cost*portion_down_payment:
        low = guess_rate
    else:
        high = guess_rate
    guess_rate = (high + low)//2
    steps += 1
    # The max amount of guesses needed is log base 2 of 10000 which is slightly
    # above 13. Once it gets to the 14th guess it breaks out of the while loop.
    if steps > 13:
        break

# output
if steps > 13:
    print('It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.')
else:
    print('Best savings rate:', rate)
    print('Steps in bisection search:', steps)
```

Why is it necessary to reset variable value current_savings and to create a for_annual_salary before the FOR loop? The current_savings has already been defined as 0 at the beginning, and why does it creates a brand new variable for_annual_salary instead of using annual_salary in FOR loop?

Comment: The annual_salary would've changed inside the for loop if no other variable hadn't been created and it must be fixed, the same occurs with the current_savings, but in this case we just need to set it to 0 at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign annual_salary to a variable and your loop changed the value of it then you can access its previous value which user entered.
eg:

```
annual_salary = input("Enter salary")
annual_salary = 10000 + 1000
print(annual_salary ) #would give you 11000, And you got some bug in your code and you want to debug what user entered the salary.
You print("annual_salary") #And you get updated salary not what user entered.
```

If you created a variable like below:

```
annual_salary = input("Enter salary")
new_annual_salary = 10000 + 1000 # some operations
print(new_annual_salary ) #Every operation was performed on new variable and if code goes wrong somewhere,you still can find new and old value of annual_salary.
print(annual_salary)
```

2. Same for current_savings

And you need to set those variables to initially 0 because when you performing operation you need to provide some number/initial value.

```
c = 0
for i in range(3):
    c+= i
print(c) # You will get 3 not 0
```

---

```
d #If you don't initialize your value and performing operations you'll get undefined error
d+= 1
print(d)
```

## NameError: name 'd' is not defined